# How to identify a key press from a bluetooth low energy tag on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am currently working on a project involving interaction with Bluetooth Low Energy tag and iPhone. I want to know how I could register a key pressed on the bluetooth tag on the iPhone.
i.e When a user presses a key on the tag, the app on the iPhone should be able to recognize and perform a certain function (say emit a sound).

I am using a Texas Instruments 2540 tag and was referrring to their sample code. In their code,

> > A key press notification has to be enabled. 
> >     When a key is pressed on the tag, the corresponding service and characteristics UUID value gets updated.
> >     In the app, the 'didUpdateValueForCharacteristic" delegate method gets called and appropriate functions can be called.

However, the company designing the bluetooth tag insists that a service be created on the iPhone app (iPhone acting as a Bluetooth server) and the bluetooth tag will alert the iPhone acting as a client.

My code excerpt is

> define Key_Press_Notification_Service             0xFFE0 
>   define Key_Press_Notification_Characterisitc      0xFFEA
>
> -(void) enableButtons:(CBPeripheral *)p 
> {
>       [self notification: Key_Press_Notification_Service characteristicUUID:Key_Press_Notification_CharacterisitcUUID p:p
>   on:YES]; 
> }
>
> //
>   -(void) notification... Method 
>   
>   // - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic.. Method

Can you help me on whether this is possible ?
And how I could register a key pressed from the BlueTooth tag to be identified on the iPhone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manjua,

Once you have your peripheral and forCharacteristic:characteristic you just need to enable the notifications:

```
// begin notification for the characteristic.
[peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
```

You then use your CBPeripheralDelegate to receive the updates:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne Murray ! I got the right charUUID from the manufacturer and voila, it worked fine.. Thanks again... One more addition to your solution is that we also need to run the                              
- [self notification:Service_UUID characteristicUUID:Characteristic_UUID p:peripheral on:YES]

also on the device. Then it works like a charm !!

Comment: Generally, it's wrong. Immediate Alert is write-only non-notification characteristic.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a "FindMe profile" scenario, described in http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/profiles/Pages/ProfileViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.profile.find_me.xml. The "Find me locator" (bluetooth tag) and "Find me target" (iPhone) each should have an "Immediate Alert" service. The Immediate Alert service behaviour is described in http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.immediate_alert.xml.

When a key is pressed on your tag, it should perform a write on the Alert Level characteristic residing on the iPhone.

Alternatively you can make your own custom profile. I.e. some characteristic on the tag performs a notification when a key is pressed. Your iPhone app would then subscribe to this characteristic and be notified of any key presses. Custom profiles would of course mean that your tag won't be out-of-the-box compatible with Bluetooth Smart Ready devices.

Comment: Thanks Fiddlebit. Does this mean I will have to create a service (CBService) on the iPhone ? Can you help me on how I could implement this ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to implement a service on the iPhone for the FindMe profile. I'm afraid I don't have any experience with iOS development though :( So I can't help you with specifics

Comment: Thanks again FiddleBit.. I have observed that the iPhone cannot act as a server on Bluetooth 4. Therefore I have implemented the solution as indicated by Murray (and hence marked his answer right). Thats just to help other developers though. Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: @Manju are you able to implement CBService on the iPhone? if yes, please help me also.

Comment: @nilam_mande : If you can raise a question on StackOverflow with the details of your issue, perhaps we can review it and comment on it better ?